# Setting FontSize on ComboBox items

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I inherited the following style for a combo box:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="64"/>-->
    <!--<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>-->
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Border x:Name="tst">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton 
                        Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton1}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                        Style="{x:Null}"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        Focusable="True" 
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Visibility="Hidden"
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid 
                            Background="LightGray"
                          Name="DropDown"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush1}"
                                BorderThickness="2"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush1}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Pink"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
                        Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If I change the FontSize in the style, it only changes the size of the ComboBox, not the size of the text inside.

If I set the TextElement.FontSize in the ContentPresenter, it has no effect.

I also have this in my styles, but changing the FontSize property here has no effect either. I also tried setting TextElement.FontSize for the ContentPresenter.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="64"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Border
                  Name="Border"
                  Padding="2"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TestBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What am I missing?

Adding templates:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox" >
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="Black" />
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton1" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border
                x:Name="Border" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              CornerRadius="2"
              Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush1}"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="1" />
        <Border 
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" 
                  Margin="1" 
                  Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush1}" 
                  BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
        <Path 
              x:Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"     
              Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush1}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush1}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CollapsedComboBoxColor}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush1}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CollapsedComboBoxColor}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush1}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource EnabledArrowBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: You have a template set to the TextBox within the ComboBox.ControlTemplate via `Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"` this may be overriding the font you set from the ComboBoxTemplate. I tried in a sample app without the template for the TextBox and it works (means text is displayed at font size 64).

Comment: I removed the Template property completely, but got the same result. A larger combobox but the text size was the same.

Comment: That's right, that shouldn't have come into picture as that textbox is for when the ComboBox.IsEditable is true. Since, I didn't have that template and removing that worked for me I thought that was the root cause. For you, it looks like there is some other code which is overriding this value.

Comment: Just realized, it could be your ToggleButton template (Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton1}" ). I have removed this as well as I don't have code for that template. Try removing that or try and see if it has anything that overriding the FontSize./

Comment: I removed the Template property on the ToggleButton and still the same result.

Comment: Post those two templates as well. I will try with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with my situation.

There was another Resource Dictionary file that was styling TextBlocks. This was overriding the text size inside of the ComboBox.

Anyone researching a similar problem that comes across this post, please be aware that a ComboBox like this has an underlying TextBlock that will pick up styles defined for them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true that the `TextBox`es inside the `ComboBox` will inherit the style set elsewhere. However, this doesn't mean you can do nothing about it.

When you specify the `ControlTemplate` for your `ComboBox` style, include the appropriate `TextBox` styles in the `ContentPresenter` and `ItemsPresenter` resource sections:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Grid>
    <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder">
      <Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle" ClickMode="Press" Template="{StaticResource ...}" Margin="15,0" Background="Transparent"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />

        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
          <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
              <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
              <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>
          </ContentPresenter.Resources>
        </ContentPresenter>

        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Foreground="White" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" Visibility="Hidden" />

        <Popup Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
          <Grid Name="DropDown" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Border Name="DropDownBorder">
              <ScrollViewer Margin="0">
                <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained">
                  <ItemsPresenter.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    </Style>
                  </ItemsPresenter.Resources>
                </ItemsPresenter>
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
          </Grid>
        </Popup>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </Grid>

  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    ...
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```